# How to save multiple repeatable fields as array in database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, themes

On the theme im working i'm trying to make slideshow. I have everything set so far i just don't understand how to save them in database when there are multiple slides.

I will skip the code as it's very large ill just add example of input values.

Each slide is made of image upload field(which is basically text field that holds link to image) and textarea field for the text in slide.

So values of the slide are like this.

```
Slide 1 -> $slide[image][0]  -- $slide[text][0]

Slide 2 -> $slide[image][1]  -- $slide[text][1]

Slide 3 -> $slide[image][2]  -- $slide[text][2]
```

It's a WordPress theme so wordpress it self is capable to save an array when it recognize it. And if anyone is familiar theme is built upon Options Framework.

When i save this, this is what i get in database.

```
a:1:{s:13:"slide_example";a:1:{s:5:"image";s:0:"";}}
```

when (i guess) it should be like this

```
a:1:{s:13:"slide_example";a:1:{s:5:"image";s:0:"slide text";};a:2:{s:5:"image";s:0:"slide text";};a:3:{s:5:"image";s:0:"slide text";}}
```

Comment: this is the default output if you serialize an array: [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Comment: Ok, this explains some things, and what those numbers means, but i still don't understand how to make this working. I have another function with repeatable text fields. But that one is only with one input field (text) and array is like $repeat_text[0],$repeat_text[1],$repeat_text[2]. Which is working very well. But this with 2 input fields per array number i don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your values should be setup like this:

```
Slide 1 -> $slide[0][image]  -- $slide[0][text]

Slide 2 -> $slide[1][image]  -- $slide[1][text]

Slide 3 -> $slide[2][image]  -- $slide[2][text]
```

Comment: That will be a bit hard to make. because values $slide[image] are coded in php and array numbers are added with javascript.

Comment: You will need to edit the js so that the number comes before the word, that's why it's not saving.

Comment: still the same, it save it exactly the same as when numbers are last.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working. Im not sure if this is proper approach but it's working for now.

I used array_map.

```
$slider = array_map(null, $slide['image'], $slide['editor'] );
```