# Saving Repeatable Fields Options to PHP Object Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

So I am trying to save a dynamically created set of fields to the database using `$_POST`. Basically, I can't figure out how to get the options to save as an object for each fieldset instead of as an array of the options themselves. It's hard for me to describe... let me explain.

First, screenshot of what the thing looks like [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s82/sh/f244d0fe-942e-4f23-920b-3e1465ccfa3e/f4df0628e1a588184df9343a9d90318d).

The fields dynamically create via jQuery and that works great. Here's the fields I have set up for the form:

```
<label>Calendar Name
    <input name="name[]" id="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $calendars['name'][$key]; ?>">
</label>
<label>Public URL
    <input name="url[]" id="url[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $calendars['url'][$key]; ?>">
</label>
<label>Color
    <input name="color[]" id="color[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $calendars['color'][$key]; ?>">
</label>
```

This is [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050050/how-to-save-multiple-repeatable-fields-as-array-in-database) but I guess I don't understand how I should be upping and sorting the index values properly using JS, or if there is a PHP solution I'm just completely missing.

TL;DR Basically how can I produce something like foo[0]['name'] instead of foo['name'][0] using either PHP or JS or both in a dynamically created form with repeating fieldsets?

Comment: You want the data to be sent in a grouping based on the row not based on the input name correct?

Comment: @Rasclatt Exactly what I am trying to do, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would post processes it like so:

```
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
            // $i is how you are going to assign your keys
            $i = 0;
            // Loop through post array
            foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $value) {
                    // Assign your new array the key values of each post array
                    $_rows[$i]['name']  =   $_POST['name'][$key];
                    $_rows[$i]['url']   =   $_POST['url'][$key];
                    $_rows[$i]['color'] =   $_POST['color'][$key];
                    $i++;
                }
        /*   Do some quick prints to see before and after
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($_POST);
             print_r($_rows);
             echo '</pre>';
        */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am doing something similar in a plugin I am working on, and this is the solution that I came up with. I modified my code to try and match what you are trying to accomplish.

Now based on your code above, I am assuming you have a post meta called `calendars`. So from there we need to modify your code a bit:

```
// Get our saved post meta if it exists
$calendars  = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_calendars', true );

// Loop through all of our calendars and display the inputs    
if ( $calendars ) { 
    foreach ( $calendars as $calendar ) { 
    ?>
        <label>Calendar Name
            <input name="name[]" id="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $calendar['name']; ?>">
        </label>
        <label>Public URL
            <input name="url[]" id="url[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $calendar['url']; ?>">
        </label>
        <label>Color
            <input name="color[]" id="color[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $calendar['color']; ?>">
        </label>    
    <?php
    }
}
```

In your save function include something like the code below:

```
$old_calendar = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_calendars', true );
$new_calendar = array();

$name   = $_POST['name'];
$url    = $_POST['url'];
$color  = $_POST['color'];

// Just to get the number of calendars we have
$count = count( $name );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {

    $new_calendar[$i]['name'] = $name[$i]; // Need sanitation if desired
    $new_calendar[$i]['url'] = $url[$i]; // Need sanitation if desired
    $new_calendar[$i]['color'] = $color[$i]; // Need sanitation if desired 

}

if ( !empty( $new_calendar ) && $new_calendar != $old_calendar )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_calendars', $new_calendar );
elseif ( empty($new_calendar) && $old_calendar )
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_calendars', $old_calendar );
```